# Instagram images not displaying in my site's IG feed, show broken images with 400 response

Tags: image, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have an Instagram feed on my site that uses the Instagram API to display and link to posts. Suddenly none of the images are displaying, and the console shows a 400 error for all of them. But if I check the image src and browse to it directly, the image works.

[image]

Comment: hey erica. have you found the solution to this problem? i have been experiencing this problem as well. the images works fine during the first few days and they start breaking after. on clicking the broken images, i still get directed to the correct instagram post.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the Headers that are restricted to **Same origin**.

[image]